# Product rule for partial differentiation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If given a function $f(x,y)$ that can be re-expressed as $g(\rho, \phi), $then by the chain rule
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}.$$
If we have to find $\partial^2 f \over \partial x^2$, is there a product rule for partial differentiation that says
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}= (\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi})\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x})+(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho})\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x})?$$
I understand the proof for product rule in normal differentiation, as in like ${d \over dx}u(x)h(x)$, but I'm not sure if we can say the same for partial differentiation. If we can, why?

Comment: Why not? The proof of the product rule for partial differentiation should be almost the same as for ordinary differentiation.

Comment: @Sobi do you have a link to the proof? I can't seem to find it on the internet.

Comment: Your first display should be $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial{\color{red}g}}{\partial\phi}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial{\color{red}g}}{\partial\rho}\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x}.$$ (One has $f(x,y)=g(\rho(x,y),\phi(x,y))$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $e_j$ is the $j$-th unit vector, then the definition of the partial derivative gives
\begin{align*}
\partial_j \big(f(x)g(x)\big) &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+he_j)g(x+he_j) - f(x)g(x)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+he_j)g(x+he_j) - f(x+he_j) g(x) + f(x+he_j) g(x) + f(x)g(x)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \left(f(x+he_j)\frac{g(x+he_j)-g(x)}{h} + g(x) \frac{f(x+he_j) - f(x)}{h} \right)\\
&= f(x) \partial_jg(x) + g(x)\partial_jf(x),
\end{align*}
assuming, of course, that our functions are differentiable in the first place.